# csv file import to mysql database using php facing error to import

Tags: php, csv, mysqli, sql-insert, mysqlimport

Importing CVS File (Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)) in phpmyadmim using php script.
When i am importing CSV File then its not importing properly into the database.
Line is terminate by ","
Please suggest me how i make it line terminate "auto", i am attaching sample file.

i am just sharing CSV File with this link
http://www.soniinfotech.com/product-data.csv

After aome suggestions and correction i am getting another issue.
Actual cvs file size is 106700 Rows and its insert 81499 rows.
I had insert files sever times but it's total rows are 81499 insert.
Please help me to fix this issue how i can insert all rows to database.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(2400);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost" , "user" , "pass" , "db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$table_name= "store";

$csv_file = "import.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$field_csv = array();
$i = 0;
while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {     if($i==0) { $i++; continue; }  // to exclude first line in the csv file.

$field_csv['productId'] = $csv_data[0];  // 1
$field_csv['title'] = $csv_data[1]; // 2
$field_csv['description'] = $csv_data[2]; // 3
$field_csv['imageUrlStr'] = $csv_data[3];  // 4
$field_csv['mrp'] = $csv_data[4]; // 5
$field_csv['price'] = $csv_data[5]; // 6
$field_csv['productUrl'] = $csv_data[6];  // 7
$field_csv['categories'] = $csv_data[7]; // 8
$field_csv['productBrand'] = $csv_data[8]; // 9
$field_csv['deliveryTime'] = $csv_data[9];  // 10
$field_csv['inStock'] = $csv_data[10]; // 11
$field_csv['codAvailable'] = $csv_data[11]; // 12
$field_csv['emiAvailable'] = $csv_data[12];  // 13
$field_csv['offers'] = $csv_data[13]; // 14
$field_csv['discount'] = $csv_data[14]; // 15
$field_csv['cashBack'] = $csv_data[15];  // 16
$field_csv['size'] = $csv_data[16]; // 17
$field_csv['color'] = $csv_data[17]; // 18
$field_csv['sizeUnit'] = $csv_data[18];  // 19
$field_csv['sizeVariants'] = $csv_data[19]; // 20
$field_csv['colorVariants'] = $csv_data[20]; // 21
$field_csv['styleCode'] = $csv_data[21]; // 22

$query = "INSERT INTO $table_name SET productId = '".$field_csv['productId']."',title = '".$field_csv['title']."',description = '".$field_csv['description']."',imageUrlStr = '".$field_csv['imageUrlStr']."',mrp = '".$field_csv['mrp']."',price = '".$field_csv['price']."',productUrl = '".$field_csv['productUrl']."',categories = '".$field_csv['categories']."',productBrand = '".$field_csv['productBrand']."',deliveryTime = '".$field_csv['deliveryTime']."',inStock = '".$field_csv['inStock']."',codAvailable = '".$field_csv['codAvailable']."',emiAvailable = '".$field_csv['emiAvailable']."',offers = '".$field_csv['offers']."',discount = '".$field_csv['discount']."',cashBack = '".$field_csv['cashBack']."',size = '".$field_csv['size']."',color = '".$field_csv['color']."',sizeUnit = '".$field_csv['sizeUnit']."',sizeVariants = '".$field_csv['sizeVariants']."',colorVariants = '".$field_csv['colorVariants']."',styleCode = '".$field_csv['styleCode']."' ";
mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
}
fclose($csvfile);

echo "CSV data successfully imported to table!!";

// close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: fgetcsv will autoamtically terminate on line breaks (provided they happen not withing text in doublequotes). The problem with your code is that you set to read 1024 bytes in one go, while your actual lines are 1500 and more. Try not limiting line size: `fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, ",")`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion martynasma. But currently i am facing another issue when this importing this file. Total rows are 106727 but its just add 81499 rows. How can i insert all rows. Plz suggest me

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your PHP file. Maybe you'll get a MySQL error on some rows.

Comment: just add error_reporting(E_ALL); code on the beginning of php script. the same result i am getting total 81499 Rows are inserted.

Comment: Are only random records missing or only the ones from the end of the file?

Comment: I checked last record from csv file and match in database and both are same. I thing randomly many rows are missing.

Comment: In that case you need to implement an error check on each insert. `if ( ! mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) ) { printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli)); }`

Comment: Okey i will check and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I am getting error "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 're two slots on the back of the cover which provide you perfect angles for viewi' at line 1"

Comment: There you have it. You probably have unescaped quotes in your text that break SQL query. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to escape each string **before** inserting into the DB. In order not to get this into chat, I'm going to sum it all up in an answer.

Comment: can you please suggest me what actual i need to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of issues with the code you provided:

### 1. Do not specify maximum line width

Specify length parameter (second parameter) to `fgetcsv()` only if you know this will be enough to read the whole line. Otherwise just use 0 (zero) to let PHP automatically detect line breaks. (it will even intelligently use new lines that actually break the lines avoiding line breaks that might happen within CSV quoted values)

```
fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, ",")
```

### 2. Escape your strings before inserting into DB

When you are inserting the string values into MySQL, you need to escape them properly. If you don't do that, and the string contains a quote, it may break your SQL query resulting in failed inserts.

Using non-escaped strings also poses the risk of [SQL-injection attack](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

To escape strings, use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function.

I.e.:

```
$field_csv['productId'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[0] );  // 1
$field_csv['title'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[1] ); // 2
$field_csv['description'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[2] ); // 3
$field_csv['imageUrlStr'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[3] );  // 4
// ... etc.
```

### 3. Use mysqli_error() to debug possible errors with your SQL queries

If you don't check for errors on your SQL queries, you're running blind. If something wrong happens, you might not even notice it.

Always check the return value of [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). (it will return boolean `FALSE` on failed query) and print out the error, using [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

```
if ( ! mysqli_query( $mysqli,$query ) ) {
  printf( "Error: %s\n", mysqli_error( $mysqli ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. now i am not getting any error, but all rows are insert twice into the database

Comment: In that case you are probably calling `mysqli_query` twice. Leave just one.

Comment: i am new in php, I just used once as i seen, where i need to make corrention ?  mysqli_query($query); then i am getting error PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: mysqly_query() expects two parameters: 1) link identifier (in your case that's `$mysqli` variable) and 2) SQL query (`$query`). If you are getting duplicate inserts it means that you are calling `mysql_query()` twice, as in the function is called twice. Look into your code, I'm sure you can find it, regardless of your the level of your experience with PHP ;)

Comment: I just remove this code and now script are working very fine.
if ( ! mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) ) {
 printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli)); }

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

set_time_limit(2400);

$mysqli = new mysqli("host" , "user" , "pass" , "db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$table_name= "store";

$csv_file = "import.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$field_csv = array();
$i = 0;
while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if($i==0) { $i++; continue; }  // to exclude first line in the csv file.

$field_csv['productId'] =mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[0] );  // 1
$field_csv['title'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[1]     ); // 2
$field_csv['description'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[2] ); // 3
$field_csv['imageUrlStr'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[3] );  // 4
$field_csv['mrp'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[4] ); // 5
$field_csv['price'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[5] ); // 6
$field_csv['productUrl'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[6] );  // 7
$field_csv['categories'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[7] ); // 8
$field_csv['productBrand'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[8] ); // 9
$field_csv['deliveryTime'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[9] );  // 10
$field_csv['inStock'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[10] ); // 11
$field_csv['codAvailable'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[11] ); // 12
$field_csv['emiAvailable'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[12] );  // 13
$field_csv['offers'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[13] ); // 14
$field_csv['discount'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[14] ); // 15
$field_csv['cashBack'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[15] );  // 16
$field_csv['size'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[16] ); // 17
$field_csv['color'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[17] ); // 18
$field_csv['sizeUnit'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[18] );  // 19
$field_csv['sizeVariants'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[19] ); // 20
$field_csv['colorVariants'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[20] ); // 21
$field_csv['styleCode'] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $csv_data[21] ); // 22


$query = "INSERT INTO $table_name SET productId = '".$field_csv['productId']."',title = '".$field_csv['title']."',description = '".$field_csv['description']."',imageUrlStr = '".

$field_csv['imageUrlStr']."',mrp = '".$field_csv['mrp']."',price = '".$field_csv['price']."',productUrl = '".$field_csv['productUrl']."',categories = '".$field_csv['categories']."',productBrand = '".

$field_csv['productBrand']."',deliveryTime = '".$field_csv['deliveryTime']."',inStock = '".$field_csv['inStock']."',codAvailable = '".$field_csv['codAvailable']."',emiAvailable = '".$field_csv

['emiAvailable']."',offers = '".$field_csv['offers']."',discount = '".$field_csv['discount']."',cashBack = '".$field_csv['cashBack']."',size = '".$field_csv['size']."',color = '".$field_csv

['color']."',sizeUnit = '".$field_csv['sizeUnit']."',sizeVariants = '".$field_csv['sizeVariants']."',colorVariants = '".$field_csv['colorVariants']."',styleCode = '".$field_csv['styleCode']."' ";
mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

}

fclose($csvfile);

echo "CSV data successfully imported to table!!";

// close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```